# Update different columns on different clauses

Tags: postgresql, update, postgresql-9.3

I have a database table in Postgres 9.3 with the following layout:

```
id   SERIAL,
col1 INT,
col2 INT
```

Whenever a new row is inserted, I will have to update ALL rows `col1` and/or `col2` in different cases but want to do it in only one (faster) query to avoid performance problems (especially because I'll have to do a lock in the table to avoid corruption).

Right now it is done with two queries:

```
UPDATE tablename 
SET col1 = col1 + 2
WHERE col1 > $VAR
```

and

```
UPDATE tablename
SET col2 = col2 + 2
WHERE col2 >= $VAR
```

note, `$VAR` is the same in both queries. It is the `col1` value of the new row.

I can't find anything related to this question in the PostgreSQL manual.

EXAMPLE DB

```
ID | col1 | col2
1  |   1  |  12
2  |   2  |  5
3  |   3  |  4
4  |   6  |  11
5  |   7  |  8
6  |   9  |  10
```

If I added a new row with `id` 7 and `col1` 5 and `col2` 6, the table would become

```
ID | col1 | col2
1  |   1  |  14
2  |   2  |  7
3  |   3  |  4
4  |   8  |  13
5  |   9  |  11
6  |   11 |  12
7  |   5  |  6
```

In this case, all rows changed at least one column. But in a table with a thousand of rows, most would not even change, so I believe using `CASE` would not be good with performance.

Comment: Not sure if CASE accepts a comparison `UPDATE t
SET    col1= CASE WHEN col1 > $VAR THEN col1+2 ELSE col1 END
,col2 = CASE WHEN col1 <= $VAR  THEN col2+2 ELSE col2 END`

Comment: Would using CASE have a better performance than two UPDATES ? (as in the worst case i would set most of the rows col1 and col2 to the same value as before)

Comment: Hitting the table once is better than 2 queries.The optimizer is smart enough to not do the update if it`s the same value as the existing one.

Comment: Mihai's suggestion is good, except that you should add a `where WHERE col1 > $VAR or col2 >= $VAR` to the update to make sure that you only touch rows that you are interested in. Otherwise that single update would be much costlier than two updates if only parts of all rows are updated.

Comment: @Mihai: This is incorrect. In Postgres, an `UPDATE` is applied to *all* rows for which `WHERE` clause evaluates to `TRUE` (or there is no `WHERE` clause). Postgres does not and **must not** decide to do nothing when it is told to do something, even if the whole row remains unchanged (some system columns do not). Triggers and other things may depend on that.

Comment: Thanks Mihal , a_horse_with_no_name and ErwinBrandstetter . As only Colin 't Hart submited that answer as an "answer", i selected it as the correct answer, but thanks Mihal for being the first to answer it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably do something like this:

```
UPDATE tablename
SET col1 = col1 + CASE WHEN col1 > $VAR THEN 2 ELSE 0 END,
    col2 = col2 + CASE WHEN col2 >= $VAR THEN 2 ELSE 0 END
WHERE col1 > $VAR OR col2 >= $VAR
```

Make sure that `col1` and `col2` are indexed if you are only updating a few rows and `tablename` has many rows.